# Change the background color of page continually does not work

Tags: javascript

I want to change the background color of page continually.
I have created a code to do what I want, but doesn't work on modern browsers like `ff`, `ch`, `IE9+`.
Also there is no any error message appear.

**The code:**

```
function randColor(colorPackage) {
    var color = "", len = colorPackage.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += colorPackage[Math.ceil(Math.random() * len)];
    }
    return color;
}

var package = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
setInterval(function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "'#" + randColor(package) + "'";
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many quotes in your style line. Change:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "'#" + randColor(package) + "'";
```

to:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randColor(package);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JYjD6/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "'#" + randColor(package) + "'";
```

to

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randColor(package);
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp) for more details on the usage of the property.